# Remember expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get this to work. I want by default to show 50 characters and the rest when I click on read more, also vice versa with the read less. Another issue I have noticed is when I click on the back browser button the read more/read less link shows but when I click on it nothing happens. Any ideas on how I can fix these two issues?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Configure/customize these variables.
        var showChar = 50;  // How many characters are shown by default
        var ellipsestext = "...";
        var moretext = "Read more";
        var lesstext = "Read less";


        $('.textControl').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {

                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }
        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='textControl'>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for basics:

```js
var extraText = ". Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum";
var originalText;
$('.moreless').click(function() {
  if (this.innerHTML === 'More...') {
    this.innerHTML = 'Less...'
    originalText = $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML;
    $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML += extraText;
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'More...'
    $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML = originalText;
  }
});
```

```html
<p class='textControl'>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>
<button class='moreless'>More...</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It saves the current text when you click "More..." and *then* adds more text. It also changes the button text to "Less...". When the button text says "Less..." it goes back to the original text, which was saved as a variable.

That's just the basic idea. For it to only show by default 50 characters, you do this:

```js
var maxText = 50;
var originalText = $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML;
var reducedText = $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML.substring(0, maxText - 1);
$('.textControl')[0].innerHTML = reducedText;
$('.moreless').click(function() {
  if (this.innerHTML === 'More...') {
    this.innerHTML = 'Less...'
    $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML = originalText;
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'More...'
    $('.textControl')[0].innerHTML = reducedText;
  }
});
```

```html
<p class='textControl'>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>
<button class='moreless'>More...</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code saves 50 characters when it starts but also saves the original text. It does the same thing when changing the button text and changing the paragraph's text.